# MobileFirst 7.1 + Ionic - App.overrideBackButton crashing

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ibm-mobilefirst

MobileFirst app with Ionic crashes upon tapping android back button (which I override with `App.overrideBackButton()` ).

I wrote a very simple test app (new project, new workspace), first without Ionic then adding Ionic references: **without Ionic everything works fine**, no inherent errors in the console, **with ionic I get two errors**:

**As soon as the app starts:**

`"Error in Success callbackId: App1084986710 : Error: Unknown event action undefined", source: file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/cordova.js (309)`

**When I tap the back button** (from page 2)

`W/UnimplementedWebViewApi(21373): Unimplemented WebView method onKeyDown called from: android.webkit.WebView.onKeyDown(WebView.java:2389)`

**Updates:**

If I remove `WL.App.overrideBackButton(goBack);` and `WL.App.resetBackButton();` from the js functions both errors persist, and the app still crashes upon tapping the back button.

If I link/include the Ionic css and js but remove any Ionic content (no ng-app property, no app.js reference from index.html) the back button override works fine.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html style="height:100%" ng-app="myTryOut" id="content">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>TryOut</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ionic.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ionicons.css">
        <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script>
    </head>
    <body onload="initLoad()">
    <div id="container">
    <!-- content will be loaded here -->

    </div>

        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
        <script src="js/messages.js"></script>
        <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
        <script src="js/ionic-bundle.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**page1.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <h2>Page 1</h2>
    <button class="button button-block button-assertive" onclick="goToPage2()">Go</button>
</html>
```

**page2.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <h2>Page 2</h2>
    <button class="button button-block button-assertive" onclick="goBack()">Back</button>
</html>
```

**main.js**

```
function wlCommonInit(){

}

function initLoad() {
    goBack();
}

function goToPage2() {
    $("#container").load("html/derp.html",function(){
        console.log("I'm in page 2");
        WL.App.overrideBackButton(goBack);
    });
}

function goBack() {
    $("#container").load("html/dorp.html",function(){
        console.log("I'm in page 1");
        WL.App.resetBackButton();
    });
}
```

**app.js**

```
var myModule = angular.module('myTryOut', ['ionic']);
```

Comment: If you remove "WL.App.resetBackButton();" from goBack(), do you still have the second problem? I suspect that WL API is not available in page2.

Comment: I tried removing "WL.App.resetBackButton();" from goBack() and still got both errors in the console (still the first one upon starting the app and the second one when pressing the back key).
I tried removing "WL.App.resetBackButton();" as well, and still got both errors.

Comment: Okay, then error 2 is not related to MFP at least.

Comment: I suggest that you will start debugging the javascript using chrome:\\inspect

Comment: Yeah the thing is chrome:\\inspect doesn't say much more about what happens, I just get an `exception firing destroy event from native` instead of error 2.

Comment: So to be clear, if you do NOT try to override the back button, then hitting back in Android crashes the app, right? So a virgin Ionic app running under MFP 7.1 in Android would demonstrate this?

Comment: If I do not override the back button, and hit the back button, error 2 fires and the app closes. The code I posted is already pretty minimal, but I'll test with a virgin MFP 7.1 app with Ionic references asap. I tried this on two android devices, Huawei P7 Ascend and Samsung Galaxy J5, both running Lollipop.

Comment: Hi Tom, do you have any logs from logcat you can share?

Comment: @RaymondCamden I answered your questions in a separate answer.